# PLSQL : where condition outside of subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I've a query like this (the original is much more complicated)

```
select 0, 999, count(case when cond = 'aa' then 1 end) val1, sum(case when cond = 'aa' then amount else 0 end) amount1,
   count(case when cond = 'bb' then 1 end) val2, sum(case when cond = 'bb' then amount else 0 end) amount2
from myTable
where amount between 0 and 999
union
select 1000, 2999, count(case when cond = 'aa' then 1 end) val1, sum(case when cond = 'aa' then amount else 0 end) amount1,
   count(case when cond = 'bb' then 1 end) val2, sum(case when cond = 'bb' then amount else 0 end) amount2
from myTable
where amount between 1000 and 2999
union
...
```

There are multiple union and the select is way more complicated.

I'd like to simplify it. For this, I used the with clause

```
with q1 as(
    select case when cond = 'aa' then 1 end val1, case when cond = 'aa' then amount else 0 end amount1,
           case when cond = 'bb' then 1 end val2, case when cond = 'bb' then amount else 0 end amount2
)
select 0, 999, sum(val1) val1, sum(amount1) amount1, sum(val2) val2, sum(amount2) amount2
from q1 where amount between 0 and 999
union
select 1000, 2999, sum(val1) val1, sum(amount1) amount1, sum(val2) val2, sum(amount2) amount2
from q1 where amount between 1000 and 2999
union
....
```

But in my case this is still very long.
Is there a possibility in plsql to write it like this

```
with q1 as (
   select minVal, maxVal, count(case when cond = 'aa' then 1 end) val1, sum(case when cond = 'aa' then amount else 0 end) amount1,
      count(case when cond = 'bb' then 1 end) val2, sum(case when cond = 'bb' then amount else 0 end) amount2
   from myTable
   where amount between minVal and maxVal
)
      select * from q1 insideWhere minVal=0 and maxVal=999
union select * from q1 insideWhere minVal=1000 and maxVal=2999
union ...
```

Or any other solution?

Comment: You could probably get some better answers, if you'd describe your real problem in more detail. I.e. what problem is the original query addressing? That way we may be able to give you better alternatives, than just blindly trying to follow your only direction (which may not necessarily be the the best, if possible at all).

Comment: it's about the same as the first query but with the
   (case when cond = 'aa' then 1 end)
with more complicated conditions and with more than 20 case and even more union
Further more the number of steps (between x an y) will change depending what is asked
and my table is already the result of a with clause

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it should be a single aggregate query, e.g.:

```
SELECT min_val,
       max_val,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cond = 'aa' THEN 1 END) val1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN cond = 'aa' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) amount1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cond = 'bb' THEN 1 END) val2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN cond = 'bb' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) amount2,
FROM   (SELECT cond,
               amount,
               CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 0 AND 999 THEN 0
                    WHEN amount BETWEEN 1000 AND 2999 THEN 1000
               END min_val,
               CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 0 AND 999 THEN 999
                    WHEN amount BETWEEN 1000 AND 2999 THEN 2999
               END max_val
        FROM   mytable) -- using a subquery here to avoid repeating the case statement in both the select column list and the group by column list
GROUP BY min_val,
         max_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're attempting you need to manifest the min/max groups into a table-like structure. You're already most of the way there: the easy way to do this is to use the `WITH` clause.

```
WITH value_groups AS
         (SELECT 0 AS min_val, 999 AS max_val FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 1000, 2999 FROM DUAL),
     q1 AS
         (SELECT *
          FROM   my_table
                 PIVOT
                     (COUNT (*) FOR cond IN ('aa' AS aa, 'bb' AS bb)))
SELECT   min_val,
         max_val,
         COUNT (aa) as val1,
         SUM (aa * amount) as amount1,
         COUNT (bb) as val2,
         SUM (bb * amount) as amount2 
FROM     q1 JOIN value_groups ON amount BETWEEN min_val AND max_val
GROUP BY min_val, max_val
```

I've also converted your `CASE` statements into a pivot. This will group matching sets of count/amount (i.e. if there are two 'aa' rows with an amount of 100, that will be returned as amount=100, count=2), which is why I'm multiplying the two to get the correct sum.